# Angular, CDK - Cannot create a draggable element dynamically

Tags: html, angular, typescript, drag-and-drop, angular-cdk

When I change the innnerHTML of an element to something like this: `<div cdkDrag>I should be draggable</div>`, the div should be draggable, but it's not.

The example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material2-issue-d1kv8a.

My angular version: 7.1.4

Comment: cdkDrag is a directive ,and it won't compiled in html strings.

Answer (score 0):

There is a difference between adding an attribute to a div, and rendering it. There is currently going on a discussion about this topic on [Github](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/8785). It seems, that there are some workarounds, but they all have downsides.